# How to solve symbolic equation in matlab

Tags: matlab, equation-solving

I have an equation in Matlab according to X parameter . I want to find the amount of X for the random amounts of F(x) .
and I tried the code below . but It gives me two different results while my equation should have just one result .

even I tried the `roots(f)` instead of `solve(f)` but it gave me an error :

> ??? Undefined function or method 'isfinite' for input arguments of
>            type 'sym'.

anybody can help me in this ?
what should I do ?
even if I have a wrong idea about solving this problem please tell me .
Thank you

> function betaDistribution_2(a,b)
>
> ```
>     syms  x ;
>     y=inline((x^(a-1))*((1-x)^(b-1)));
>     beta=quad(y,0,1);
>     g=(1/beta)*(x^(a-1))*((1-x)^(b-1));
>     % I have this equation and I want to find the amount of x for the random 
>     %amounts of p 
>     p=int(g,x,0,x); 
>
>     for i=0:50
>        fxi=rand(1);
>        f=p-fxi;
>        xi=solve(f);
>        result=eval(xi);
>        disp(result)
>     end
>
>     end
> ```

Comment: Where exactly do you get the error? Furthermore you may want to run the code after using `dbstop if error` to isolate/solve the problem.

Comment: after I used {roots(f)} instead of {solve(f)} and run the program in work space with {betaDistribution_2(1,2)} I got this error
??? Undefined function or method 'isfinite' for input arguments of type 'sym'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to filter your solutions.

```
a=1;
b=2;
% a threshold for imagery part
SMALL=1e-9;

syms x real;
y=inline((x^(a-1))*((1-x)^(b-1)));
beta=quad(y,0,1);
g=(1/beta)*(x^(a-1))*((1-x)^(b-1));
p=int(g,x,0,x);

% return true for physically meaningfull results
filter = @(xc) abs(imag(xc))<SMALL && real(xc)>0 && subs(g, x, xc) > 0 && subs(p, x, xc)>0;

for m=0:50
  fxi=rand(1);
  f=p-fxi;
  xi=solve(f, x);
  result=eval(xi);

  idx = arrayfun (filter, result);
  result = result(idx);
  % make sure it is OK
  assert(length(result)==1);
  disp(result)
end
```

Comment: No . the two results are both real .

Comment: It is possible that your system has several solutions and only one of them has a physical meaning. What is the range for `a` and `b`?

Comment: when I tried a=1 , b=2 I got 2 results .
when I tried a=3 , b=4 I got 4 results !!!!!!!!!

Comment: the range of a and b could be different and it depends on user's opinion .

Comment: I see you redefine `i`. It messes up imagery numbers. Better change it and do `clean`.

Comment: Even I chaned the code like this

 
`function betaDistribution_2(a,b)`
 
`syms  x real ;`

`y=inline((x^(a-1))*((1-x)^(b-1)));`

`beta=quad(y,0,1);`

`g=(1/beta)*(x^(a-1))*((1-x)^(b-1));`

`% I have this equation and I want to find the amount of x for the random
% amounts of p `

`p=int(g,x,0,x);`
`fxi=0.001;`

`f=p-fxi;`

    `xi=solve(f);`

    `result=eval(xi);`

    `disp(result)'


but the result was :



`'1.4370  `        
  ` 0.0379     `     
 ` -0.0189 - 0.0310i`
   `1.0814 - 0.4712i`
  ` 1.0814 + 0.4712i`
 ` -0.0189 + 0.0310i `

Comment: I don't know how to thank you . my problem finally solved . I was trying so hard but It didn't have any effect . thanks again .